# Post operation that doesn't create an resource

Tags: api-platform.com

I would like to create an POST endpoint that calculates values depending on request body. I wouldn't like create any resource in this operation, just return calculations results. Is it possible to achieve this using Api Platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You may either:

- create a controller, and return a `JsonResponse` from it in order to stop the lifecycle before it create anything, as explained [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers),
- [disable the `WriteListener`](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#built-in-event-listeners) of your custom operation: `write = false` (see below),
- [create a dummy `DataPersister`](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-persisters/#creating-a-custom-data-persister), with an empty `persist` method, if for some reasons you need to complete your lifecycle,

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *    collectionOperations = {
 *        "custom" = {
 *            "method" = "post",
 *            "write" = false",
 *            "path" = "/my/custom/path",
 *         }
 *    }
 * }
 */
```

and probably few other ways...